# Parametrizing a table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-8.3

I am working on a Postgres 8.3 database and was trying to use PL/pgSQL to create function that generates a table name based on dates input to the table:

I have to create a series of tables that are indexed by dates for example:

```
drop table one_day_11_13 cascade;
create table one_day_11_13 as
select * from master_table where
timestamp < '2012-11-14' and timestamp >= '2012-11-13';  

drop table one_day_11_14 cascade;
create table one_day_11_14 as
select * from master_table where
timestamp < '2012-11-15' and timestamp >= '2012-11-14';
```

I was thinking the way to do this would be to create a PL/pgSQL function that took as arguments `('11_13', '2012-11-14', '2012-11-13')` for example to create the first table above.  I am having trouble coding up the appropriate EXECUTE statements.

What is the best way to do this kind of thing is PL/pgSQL overkill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, consider upgrading to a more recent version. [8.3 is on its way out.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

For 8.3 it could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_recreate_tbl(date, date)
 RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- derive tablename from first date
   _tbl text := 'one_day_' || to_char($1, 'MM_YY'); 
BEGIN

 -- Use IF EXISTS to avoid an exception when table does not exist.
EXECUTE
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || _tbl || ' CASCADE';

EXECUTE 
'CREATE TABLE ' || _tbl || ' AS
SELECT *
FROM   master_table
WHERE  timestamp >= ''' || $1::text || '''::date
AND    timestamp <  ''' || $2::text || '''::date';

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_recreate_tbl('2012-11-13'::date, '2012-11-14'::date);
```

- Whenever you want to parameterize identifiers, you can't use pure SQL. Use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function or [`DO` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) (version 9.0+).
- This version is safe enough. With more flexible input you would have to sanitize identifiers and values with [`quote_ident()` and `quote_literal()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to prevent possible SQL injection.
- In modern versions (since 8.4) you would use the [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) clause to skip casting parameters to text.
- Don't use `timestamp` as column name. It's the name of a data type.
- Use `DROP TABLE` **`IF EXISTS`**. [Already available in 8.3.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-droptable.html)
- I derive the table name from the date and skip the third parameter. Seemed like a simplification.

Comment: Thank for for such a thoughtful and well written answer.  We are using a MPP database that was forked off 8.3 so thank you for keeping the answer consistent with the version in question.  I wish we had 9.0 functionality .....

Comment: Also in more modern versions you can use `format` with its `%I` format-specifier instead of `quote_ident`, making for much more readable dynamic queries.